# ldap_bind: Confidentiality required (13)

Tags: 12.04, server, ssl, openssl, openldap

I want to configure ldap with ssl so I used openssl for certificate and when I enable olcSecurity tls=1 in /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif and now when I try to use ldapsearch or try to login it gives this message ldap_bind: Confidentiality required (13).
Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`, set:

```
SSL start_tls
TLS_REQCERT never
```

(Add the second line if you're using a self-signed certificate.)

Comment: not working again I am getting the same error message

Comment: The answer is below. add -Z to ldapsearch

Answer (score 4):

From the openldap site I found this that should help you

Normally the error message in your subject is as a result of the server 
requiring encryption of some kind. For example, you might have set:

```
security tls=1
```

or similar, in which case you need to use `ldaps://` or start_tls (`-Z`):

```
[bgmilne@comanche ~]$ ldapsearch -x -LLL "(uid=bgmilne)" 1.1
ldap_bind: Confidentiality required (13)
        additional info: TLS confidentiality required
[bgmilne@comanche ~]$ ldapsearch -Z -x -LLL "(uid=bgmilne)" 1.1
dn: uid=bgmilne,ou=People,dc=ranger,dc=dnsalias,dc=com
```

A quick summery is open a terminal and use

```
ldaps://
```

or

```
start_tls (-Z):
```

To start your prosses

Comment: this command shows nothing

Comment: Did you try both

Comment: Does the following mean anything to you You must have a "ssf" setting in your slapd.conf/slapd.d

Comment: yes I try both of them but I don't know about ssf

Comment: I dont use the program so just trying to troubleshoot here : Does this mean anything to you : Turn on the "Allow Clear Text Password" or tick off the "Required TLS for
simple binds with password" box on the LDAP Group object in ConsoleOne

Comment: This is a very complex subject I beleve this information may be useful to you http://www.linuxlasse.net/linux/howtos/OpenLDAP_Server,_authenticate_linux_users

Comment: The -Z option you mentioned helped me. I don't know why I didn't think of it since I used it with ldapsearch...